# Bind a process to a logical device (set_visible for logical devices)

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have multiple fits (multi-processed) and I want to set GPU logical device/s for each process given N number of physical GPUs.

*The following is a hypothetical example:* I have 8 fits (8 processes) and 2 GPUs. I would like to make 16 logical GPUs and I would like each fit/process to see only 2 logical GPUs.

Making 16 logical GPUs is no issue. But from my search, there is only [set_visible_devices](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/set_visible_devices), and no method for logical devices. How would I be able to achieve such thing?